# OpenStreetMap static overlay over an area of GPS points

Tags: openstreetmap

I am writing an Android programm where you can fill out parking tickets automatically.
Moreover, this programm has an OSM built in, where your current location is marked.

Now, I want to show all zones where a parking ticket is being needed!
I have all the coordinates for it, however, marking everything on the fly would be very time consuming. That`s why I would like to do it in a static way, but I do not know whether that is possible or not?

Maybe, someone could give me a hint how to solve this problem?

Thank you very much in advance!

BR,
Bernd

Comment: How do you display your map at the moment?

Comment: At the moment I am able to display the map and the current location. Before I changed to OSM, I did all the things in GoogleMaps. I had stored the coordinates in files, then iterate through the files and drawed polygons over the defined area. This, however, was very slow, it took nearly 2 minutes to accomplish the task. Now I want to solve it in OSM, because I like it more than GoogleMaps, but I do not know how to accomplish my task. OSM should load more or less quite fast. I think it should be possible with some static overlay, but I am not quite sure.

Comment: Yeah but I asked *how* you are displaying your map. Because this heavily influences which kinds of overlays are possible for you. In order to receive an helpful answer you have to tell us something about your technical details.

Comment: Hm, okay, at the moment I just display the current location of the user. Now, I want to draw all zones where you would need a parking ticket. I have no clue, how to do it in an efficient way. As I did it in GoogleMaps, I have had no efficient way to accomplish that, too. That`s why I thought, maybe, somebody could give me a hint or the right direction? I hope it answered your question better? This is how I display the current location: http://android-er.blogspot.co.at/2012/05/display-current-location-marker-on.html

Comment: maybe I found an answer for my question. Using leaflet will solve my problems I think!

Comment: ok, now I know that leaflet would fit for me, but there is one thing left that I do not know: maybe someone has a full and simple example how to implement this in android. the informations on the website are not good enough for me to understand. maybe someone has a simple example with android code, leaflet.css or so for me - Thank you very much in advance!